# Android projects are overriding each other

Tags: android, eclipse, project

Anyone here who has experience with 2 Android projects which are overriding each other? I can't have the first one installed if I want to install the second one, because it will result in an error. I have already tried to create a new project and copy the source code of the second app in it, but I am having the same problem. Also tried to clean my workspace with the "-clean" command, but it didn't help. Anyone who knows a solution?

The error says that the package of my first activity (which is my splash screen) does not exits. Except when I haven't already installed app number one, because then everything works fine...

Thanks in advance.

@EDIT:

The error:

```
[2013-06-28 10:06:09 - KCStandaard] Starting activity com.android.standard.actSplash on device 1e0dc11e
[2013-06-28 10:06:09 - KCStandaard] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-06-28 10:06:12 - KCStandaard] Starting activity com.android.standard.actSplash on device 1e0dc11e
[2013-06-28 10:06:13 - KCStandaard] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-06-28 10:06:16 - KCStandaard] Starting activity com.android.standard.actSplash on device 1e0dc11e
[2013-06-28 10:06:17 - KCStandaard] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-06-28 10:06:20 - KCStandaard] Starting activity com.android.standard.actSplash on device 1e0dc11e
[2013-06-28 10:06:20 - KCStandaard] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]   cmp=com.koeriers.tools/com.android.standard.actSplash }
[2013-06-28 10:06:20 - KCStandaard] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-06-28 10:06:23 - KCStandaard] Starting activity com.android.standard.actSplash on device 1e0dc11e
[2013-06-28 10:06:24 - KCStandaard] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.koeriers.tools/com.android.standard.actSplash }
[2013-06-28 10:06:24 - KCStandaard] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2013-06-28 10:06:24 - KCStandaard] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.koeriers.tools/com.android.standard.actSplash} does not exist.
```

I am only getting this error when either the first or the second app is already installed. And I am trying to run the other one.

Comment: Do they use the same package name?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "overriding"? What happens, step by step, what is the error **exactly**, etc.?

Comment: @Konstantin No they don't. The first uses com.android.standard and the second one uses com.android.second.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato they can't be installed together. When the first one is installed and I trying to install the second one it just replace the first app with the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the application by right-clicking project>Android Tools>Rename application package, hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `com.android` as part of the package name.

I repeat, do not use the `com.android` as part of the package name. That's the system package name, not your package name.

Comment: I've replaced in both apps the android part with example. But the problem still exists

Comment: Yes, Eclipse is horrible with refactoring package names. You have to rename them, then you have to manually correct the manifest file, and anywhere the com.android appears that's not part of the system (whether an application package name or an Activity package name). You'll also have to redo all your imports, so that they don't mention android.R (even if those android.R are not underlined in red).

Comment: I finally succeed to solve the problem. Although I am not sure which answer I should mark as "accepted". Because you and user2523388 both gave me the solution which eventually worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If in the second project you're including the first one or parts of it etc. you will most probably have problems installing it. If that's not the case, paste the code here or provide a link, so that we can see where the problem might be.

Comment: In both app there is indeed a package which exists in both apps with the same name. But that one acts more like a library although it isn't marked or included like a library. Can that cause a problem like this?

Comment: Is this package essentially the same (the same cksum for example) in both of the projects?

Comment: Please to also specify the package names of the two applications.

Comment: In both apps the package is named com.example.tools and just provides the "tools" or the functions for the app. There is a package which provides the ui with the user. And I've got that com.example.tools packages to provide the functionality